# Can’t add a fixed color in the background

Tags: compositing-nodes

I’m trying to add a fixed color (say white) in the background… however it is surprisingly challenging. I tried to enable transparent film mode and then use the compositor like:

[image]

You can see that the white is actually more like a "grey".

(I made sure to disable filmic look, as I understand that blender can’t deal with different color space in the compositor, but still no luck)

Any solution? I don’t want to use another tool like ffmpeg on transparent pictures as I want to export to jpg that takes significantly less space than png/exr.

Comment: Check the alpha channel of your render.  This usually works without any issues.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Well the alpha contains only 0 values (according to Krita), like all channels, and in krita adding a white background gives me a perfect white as expected.

Comment: Could you share the file? unable to reproduce that on my side. Please use https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @lemon problem solved, I was not changing the CM in the right tab!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, Forester (thanks!) made me realize that the color management should be changed in another tab, the one I changed should be left with the default setting:

[image: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/285639647567282179/1103732590336278698/image.png?width=234&height=556]

Another trick to mix filmic and non-filmic (thanks again!) is to stay in filmic but manually add a value of around 10 instead of the maximum 1 (the higher the closer to actual white it will be, but you will get ugly aliasing with too high values)